# How adjust "line" thickness of a plot type n in R

Tags: r, plot, graph

I am plotting a graph with these parameters below:

```
plot(c(1, max(Nmax)), c(1, max(Smax)), xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, 
   type = "n", main = title_plot, bty="L", las=1,  font.lab=2, lwd.tick=2)
```

My plot is of **type="n"** which means type "n" does not produce any points or lines. However I want to increase the thickness of drawed lines. I have already tried **lwd**, but it seems that it only works if type is set to "l". How can I achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not catching what you want to achieve. If you set `type = "n"` clearly you don't want to plot any points or lines. Why do you want to increase the width of the lines? Maybe you want to add lines at a later time using `lines()`?

Comment: Are you talking about subsequently drawn lines, with, e.g., `lines()`? Or are you talking about the plot border, etc., that are drawn by this `plot(..., type = "n")` call?